# Flutter Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'storage/emulated/0/newcreatefoldr' ( Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Flutter/ This is my code for creating folder using pathProdiver package

note: i have set the permission in manifest file as a

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I do not what is the real problem here, the compiler says permission is denied but i set all the permissions.

```
Future<String> askForPermission() async {
  final folderName = "newcreatefoldr";
  final path = Directory("storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
  var status=await Permission.storage.status;
  if(!status.isGranted){
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if(await path.exists()){
    return path.path;

  }else{
    path.create();
    return path.path;
  }

}
```

and the error saying ....

```
E/flutter (24174): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'storage/emulated/0/newcreatefoldr' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

for more detailed this is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cameraapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="cameraapp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I  solved this problem with the following solutions: For android 10/Q, I have added this permission in the androidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

and add this line in application tag:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

For android 11/R, add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

In app-user permission handler I'm checking permissions with the following function:

```
Future<bool> _hasAcceptedPermissions() async {
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage) &&
      // access media location needed for android 10/Q
      await _requestPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation) &&
      // manage external storage needed for android 11/R
      await _requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  // not android or ios
  return false;
}}
```